# How to install php5-fpm on debian?

Tags: nginx, apt, php-fpm

I am trying to install php5-fpm on Debian 6.0.5 and after trying to install php5-fpm:

> E: couldn't find package php5-fpm

Ok, so I tried to add non official repository:

> add-apt-repository ppa:l-mierzwa/lucid-php5

But it says:

> add-apt-repository command not found

What can I do now?

Comment: PPAs are for Ubuntu, not Debian. What you're trying to do will not work.

Comment: OK so answer my question with different solution and dont vote down :)

Comment: I didn't vote you down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After about twelve seconds of searching for the answer, it turns out that the [Dotdeb](http://www.dotdeb.org/) repository has the packages you want.

Here are the [instructions](http://www.dotdeb.org/instructions/) on how to use it.

Comment: @Chopper3 You honor me sir

Comment: Thank you Chopper3 ... i was searching for solution for 30 minutes and browsing ubuntu forums ... only solution i found was this: http://www.betamaster.us/blog/?p=866 ...